# How to only get users of a certain age based on Date of Birth

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a User model with a method to get the age.

```
public function age() {
      return $this->date_of_birth->diffInYears(\Carbon\Carbon::now());
    }
```

That works fine.

In a controller I'm trying to get all users over 16, but the issue is users don't need to enter their DOB on signup, only later in the app. How to I retrieve records of all users of a certain age, and discount null entries.

I've tried this

```
public function index(){

      $users = User::whereNotNull('date_of_birth')->take(10);

      if(!empty($users)){
        $validusers = $users->age();
      }


      return view('egistrations.index', compact('validusers'));
    }
```

But i get the following error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::age()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index(){

    $users_with_age = User::whereNotNull('date_of_birth')
                ->take(10)
                ->get()
                ->each(function ($user) {
                    $user->age = $user->age();
                });
    return view('egistrations.index', compact('users_with_age'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function index(){

```
  $users = User::whereNotNull('date_of_birth')->take(10);

  if(!empty($users)){
    $validusers = $users->get();
  }


  return view('egistrations.index', compact('validusers'));
}
```

you need to use **get()** as above or you can use **all()**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add **get()** in your query

```
$users = User::where('date_of_birth','!=',NULL)->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use  [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) to use `$user->age`

```
public function index(){

      $users = User::whereNotNull('date_of_birth')->take(10)->get();

      if(!empty($users)){

          $validusers = $users->map(function($user){
             return  $user['age'] = $user->age();
         });

      }


      return view('egistrations.index', compact('validusers'));
    }
```